# How should view helper methods from /lib be accessed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some methods wrapped in Modules under [app]/lib, the lib folder has been added to config.autoload_paths, and I've also `Include MyHelper` to the ApplicationController class.

The error (in the view) is:

```
undefined local variable or method
```

I'm using the lib directory as these would be methods that are not app specific.

Uhh there was a comment for "more" code.

**lib/my_helper.rb**

```
module MyHelper
   def my_tag
       "<div>hello</div>"
   end
end
```

**config/application.rb**

```
... 
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
...
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    include MyHelper
    ...
end
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
...
<%= my_tag %>
...
```

Comment: Please post more code.

Comment: why not just put your helper module into app/helpers floder?

Comment: Simply put... it's a generic method. It *shouldn't* be in the app/helpers folder.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `include MyHelper`, `helper MyHelper` should have been used.